QGIS - Extract with expression - one occurrence each - if ID IS NULL
I'm currently configuring the 'Extract by expression' algorithm to achieve the following:

Keep all values where 'ID_IMPCT' IS NOT NULL.
Keep only one occurrence of each unique feature in 'LIB_PHYSIO' where 'ID_IMPCT' is always NULL.
(This means if any identical features have a non-NULL value in 'ID_IMPACT', the condition is broken.)

For example, If I have this table:

The result would be:


Only one entity is kept for Hab 1, Hab 2, and Hab 4 (because ID_IMPCT always NULL).
Hab 3 is always kept (because 'ID_IMPCT' is not NULL).
Hab 5 contains an entity with 'ID_IMPCT' not NULL, so it is kept (therefore, not the others when they are NULL).


Use the expression below:

case 
when 
ID_IMPCT is NOT NULL
then 1
else 
    if (
        array_min(
            array_agg( @id, group_by:=LIB_PHYSIO)
        ) = @id,
        1,
        0
    )
end


To make it work on the "extract with expression algorithm" I adapted code in @Babel’s answer this way :
ID_IMPCT is NOT NULL OR array_min(array_agg( @id, group_by:=LIB_PHYSIO)) = @id

In this way, some errors might occur.
If we have several identical values, the first one with 'ID_IMPCT' = NULL will be accepted since it is the first entry. Consequently, the others will also be accepted if they have 'ID_IMPCT' = NOT NULL.
This is not the expected behavior. Therefore, I adjusted it in my case based on the value contained in another column.
ID_IMPCT is NOT NULL OR (array_min(array_agg( @id, group_by:=LIB_PHYSIO)) = @id AND NOT array_contains(array_agg("layer", group_by:=lib_physio), 'Intersection'))

